# Is there a `declare` keyword in ES6/7?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Recently I've been studying ES6, and that lead to me using Babel a lot. Being the curious type, I started looking at the Babel Github repository to know how they built this awesome tool, and know if I can somehow contribute.

However, I came across [this file](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/lib/types.js), and it has things like `declare class BabelNodeSourceLocation {}` written all over it, and the file ends with .js.

This got me very confused, and I am now wondering whether there's a declare keyword in JavaScript that I didn't know of, or is this just a Babel-specific syntax? All my Google searches resulted in nothing.

**Update:**  Putting the code in the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=true&code=declare%20class%20BabelNodeArrowFunctionExpression%20extends%20BabelNode%20%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20%22ArrowFunctionExpression%22%3B%0A%20%20params%3A%20any%3B%0A%20%20body%3A%20BabelNodeBlockStatement%20%7C%20BabelNodeExpression%3B%0A%20%20async%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%20%20returnType%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A) resulted in nothing. Babel just ignored the code and did not produce any equivalent ES5 output. It also did not throw any error.

Comment: Interesting. I think that is typescript. Not sure why it has the `.js` extension.

Answer (score 19):

> and the file ends with .js.

That doesn't mean a lot these days :-)

> I am wondering whether there's a `declare` keyword in JavaScript that I didn't know of

No, there is not.

> Or is this just a Babel-specific syntax?

No. It is a [type declaration file](http://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html#example) for the Flow typechecker.

Comment: I guess it's rather Flow.

Comment: @FelixKling: You're right. It's not a `.d.ts` suffix :-)

Comment: From the [Babel repository](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/scripts/generate-interfaces.js): _"add script to generate a flow lib file for babel types"_

Comment: @zeroflagL: Ah, I didn't look at the [history](https://github.com/babel/babel/commits/master/scripts/generate-interfaces.js).

Comment: This becomes confusing with `import` statements used to pull in a declared module. `flow-typed` makes type imports available by importing the types by the same string as the npm module name. Magically, flow seems to now then that these import statements refer to the content in the `flow-typed` directory, and not the module itself. But how webpack, babel, and something like eslint treat this is quite unclear. this has come up for me in trying to create custom flow types and make them importable. See [here](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/2254)

Comment: Note that there is also a `declare` keyword in Typescript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript

Answer (score 14):

With Flow, you can declare a global class that allows you to reference the class type anywhere in your project.  This has no affect on runtime code and won't affect babel output.

An example from [the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/#toc-declaring-a-global-class):

```
declare class URL {
  constructor(urlStr: string): URL;
  toString(): string;

  static compare(url1: URL, url2: URL): boolean;
};
```

And then in your project you can reference URL as a class type.

Similarly, you can declare other global Types, Modules, Functions, Variables.  A good way to keep them organized.

Comment: Note that there is also a `declare` keyword in Typescript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript