# Purpose of `declare` keyword in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

What is the meaning of the `declare` keyword?

```
type Callback = (err: Error | String, data: Array<CalledBackData>) => void;
```

vs.

```
declare type Callback = (err: Error | String, data:Array<CalledBackData>) => void;
```

Cannot find docs that explain the purpose of the `declare` keyword in TS. Qué significa?

Answer (score 365):

**TL;DR**

`declare` is used to tell the compiler "this thing (usually a variable) exists already, and therefore can be referenced by other code, also there is no need to compile this statement into any JavaScript".

**Common Use Case:**

You add a reference to your web page to a JavaScript file that the compiler knows nothing about. maybe it is a script coming from some other domain like 'foo.com'. when evaluated the script will create an object with some useful API methods and assign it to the identifier 'fooSdk' on the global scope.

You want your TypeScript code to be able to call `fooSdk.doSomething()`, but since your compiler does not know `fooSdk` variable exists, you will get a compilation error.

You then use the `declare` keyword as a way of telling the compiler "trust me, this variable exists and has this type". The compiler will use this statement to statically check other code but will not trans-compile it into any JavaScript in the output.

```
declare const fooSdk = { doSomething: () => boolean }
```

Newer Typescript version require a slightly different syntax:

```
declare const fooSdk : { doSomething: () => boolean }
```

In the same vein, you can add the declare keyword to class properties to tell the compiler not to emit any code that would create this property, assuming you have your own code that would create it that the compiler does not know about or does not understand.

Your specific example is different since you are declaring a type, not a variable, types already do not compile into any JavaScript. I do not know if there is any reason to declare a type.

Comment: `declare const fooSdk = { doSomething: () => boolean }` gives **A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal or literal enum reference.** and **'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here** errors, how does this answer gets such a high rating?

Comment: @fires3as0n I tested and found a different syntax that works on current version Typescript. added to answer.

Comment: Can you please add links to the typescript documentation ? It's an almost good answer, and would become a good answer with some links to verify the statements.

Comment: Is it fair to say that a *ambient module* file (`d.ts`) can be used instead of `declare`? In other words, that `declare` is used in the module in question, whereas an ambient module lives outside the file and is brought into scope with a `/// <reference ....`?

Answer (score 242):

Here is a real world example.

I have a TypeScript React app that uses the Webpack Hot Middleware. The Webpack Hot Middleware is not written in TypeScript, but in good old-fashioned JavaScript. So it has no type declarations that the TypeScript compiler can check against.

When I run my code, the object `module` from the Webpack Hot Middleware exists, and I can console.log it despite it being good old-fashioned JavaScript hiding in my fancy new TypeScript React app.

The `module` object also has keys, such as `module.hot`, and the keys can have values. But the TypeScript design time compiler (in VSCode at least) draws a red squiggly under it saying `property 'hot' does not exist`. But it does exist!

To make the TypeScript compiler agree, declare it like this:

```
declare let module: any
```

The existing `module` object, now has a type of `any`, which makes the TypeScript compiler happy now, red squiggly gone and now I can continue to compile and write my other code.

If you remove the keyword `declare`, and just write `let module: any`, it will not compile, instead saying that `'module' already exists`. That's what "ambient" in the accepted answer means.

Comment: `declare` specifies a type to an already existing variable, not declaring a new one.

Comment: is this like **extern** keyword of C language which was used to declare things that are outside of our source code and compiler cannot access it? Only linker would link them later. so extern would enable the code compilation that otherwise would produce errors

Comment: I love this explanation, so useful: `If you remove the keyword declare, and just write let module: any, it will not compile, instead saying that 'module' already exists. That's what "ambient" in the accepted answer means.`

Answer (score 39):

From Typescript docs:

[Typescript - Working with Other JavaScript Libraries](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries)

> To describe the shape of libraries not written in TypeScript, we need to **declare** the API that the library exposes. Because most JavaScript libraries expose only a few top-level objects, namespaces are a good way to represent them.
>
> **We call declarations that don’t define an implementation “ambient”.** Typically these are defined in .d.ts files. If you’re familiar with C/C++, you can think of these as .h files. Let’s look at a few examples.
>
> #### Ambient Namespaces
>
> The popular library D3 defines its functionality in a global object called d3. Because this library is loaded through a  tag (instead of a module loader), its declaration uses namespaces to define its shape. For the TypeScript compiler to see this shape, we use an ambient namespace declaration. For example, we could begin writing it as follows:
>
> ***D3.d.ts (simplified excerpt)***
>
> ```
> declare namespace D3 {
>     export interface Selectors {
>         select: {
>             (selector: string): Selection;
>             (element: EventTarget): Selection;
>         };
>     }
>     // (...)
> }
> ```

Answer (score 26):

You can use declare to tell the compiler about types before you write any implementation code and TypeScript will be happy.

```
declare function foo(name: string): string
```

Comment: Short and sweet :thumbs_up:

Answer (score 21):

Consider this scenario: You have a Typescript project. Then you decide to write a module in JavaScript for whatever reason and use it in your Typescript code.

```
// getMyName.js
module.exports = function getMyName(name) {
    return name;
}
```

Then you import it into your typescript code

```
// myCode.ts
import getMyName from 'getMyName'; //getMyName is a JS module not typescript
```

When importing that JS module(`allowJs` compiler option should be set to `false` otherwise, JS files will be resolved without any type definitions), Typescript's compiler complains about that module not being a module at all!

`Could not find a declaration file for module '/absolute/path/to/getMyName.ts'`

This is because Typescript doesn’t resolve to JS code by its own. To circumvent this problem we should provide type definition (`filename.d.ts`) for our JS module. To do so you can use `declare` and `export`.

```
// getMyName.d.ts
declare function getMyName(name: string): string;

export default getMyName;
```

After that when we import our JS module, typescript doesn't complain about anything because it now has access to the types.

Comment: `import getMyName from 'getMyName';` is the `default` export, maybe you meant `import {getMyName} from 'getMyName'`;

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes you're right. edited.

Answer (score -2):

delcare key words use when you import some library not have the declare type files,such as *.d.ts

after that vs eslint not check the syntax and context , will let you pass, if you default use tsc compiler, that the good reason to declare to remove syntax error

Comment: This is not correct; the declare keyword is not for that purpose, but it is used in that scenario.