# Trouble Using Microsoft BotFramework-WebChat in Angular 2 Application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chatbot

I'm having some trouble implementing the botframework into my angular application which is running locally, as per the docs

### Easy: In your non-React website, run Web Chat inline

*Add a DirectLine (not Web Chat) channel, and generate a Direct Line Secret. Make sure to enable Direct Line 3.0.*

*Include botchat.css and botchat.js on your website, e.g.:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="bot"/>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
<script>
  BotChat.App({
    directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
    user: { id: 'userid' },
    bot: { id: 'botid' },
    resize: 'detect'
  }, document.getElementById("bot"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I've inserted my local path to the built CSS in the header as well as the js file, then in my component, I've declared the variable BotChat

```
declare var BotChat;
```

and then I've put the script in my constructor

```
constructor() {
    BotChat.App({
    directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
    user: { id: 'userid' },
    bot: { id: 'botid' },
    resize: 'detect'
  }, document.getElementById("bot"));
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working im getting this error in the console also

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source 
“http://localhost:4200/BotFramework-WebChat-master/botchat.js”
```

and

```
Error: [object Object]
Stack trace:
resolvePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7633:31
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does your console give you any errors? Mind showing us the error logs?

Comment: @ton Yeah I get `ERROR in C:/path/path/angular/src/app/chatsidebar/chatsidebar.component.ts (69,5): Cannot find name 'BotChat'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after playing around with it for a while, Ive figured it out.

To use the botchat framework in your existing angular application put the botchat folder you download from github in the src folder. run `npm install` and `npm build` on the botchat folder in your project. Link the built js and css files in your angular.cli.

In your component

```
import { component, ViewAfterInit } from @angular/cli;

declare var BotChat; //important
```

then

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' }, //DONT ACTUALLY PUT IN YOUR BOT ID IT WILL BREAK THE APP
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));
}
```

and that will make it work in your angular application.

Answer (score 1):

In your chatsidebar.component.ts add after all imports statement

`declare var BotChat;`

This is actually typescript way of telling you have some global variable declared somewhere else, and you want to use it.

[declare keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript)

Also please try using renderer2 of angular instead of direct dom manipulation.

[Angular renderer](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/)

Comment: I get this error `"Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: BotChat is not defined\`

Comment: Have you included script tag & css files defined in example in your index.html?

Comment: Ive got the framework saved locally and Im linking to the locally saved dist files in the header of index.html

Comment: Ive re compiled and now im getting this error `Error: [object Object]
Stack trace:
resolvePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7633:31`

Comment: It looks like you have some error in your build process.

Comment: any ideas on how I might be able to fix that?