# What is the purpose of using 'declare' keyword in a class declaration in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I saw some code in **vscode** sourcecode and rewirte it in a simple version.

I want to know the purpose of using **declare** in the code below:

```
interface IDog {
    readonly color: string
}

class Doggy {
    public color = "";
}

class Doggy2 implements IDog {
    //Here is the code as mentioned
    declare readonly color: string;
}

const aaa = new Doggy()
const bbb = new Doggy2()
```

In the compiled code, **color** in class **Doggy2** was ignored. Is this a normal usage of **declare**? Where can I learn these *special* codes in Typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of declare keyword in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript)

Comment: I know the common usage of declare, but why use this in a class property?

Comment: Maybe this the answer I need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552002/7254992  in the same link.
**In the same vein you can add the declare keyword to class properties to tell the compiler to not emit any code that would create this property, assuming you have your own code that would create it that the compiler does not know about or does not understand.**