# React Typescript FunctionalComponent without assigning function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I came across this part of code for defining `FormWithRedirect` as a `FC(FunctionComponent)`:

```js
declare const FormWithRedirect: FC<FormWithRedirectProps>;
export declare type FormWithRedirectProps = FormWithRedirectOwnProps & Omit<FormProps, 'onSubmit' | 'active'>;
export interface FormWithRedirectOwnProps {
  defaultValue?: any;
  record?: Record;
  redirect?: RedirectionSideEffect;
  render: (props: Omit<FormViewProps, 'render' | 'setRedirect'>) => React.ReactElement<any, any>;
  ...
}
```

And here is how it is used:

```js
const SimpleForm: FC<SimpleFormProps> = (props) => (
  <FormWithRedirect {...props} render={(formProps) => <SimpleFormView {...formProps} />} />
);
```

considering the definition of `FC` as below:

```js
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

I suppose there should be assignment to `FormWithRedirect` before using it (something like `FormWithRedirect = (props) => {....}`), however in the code above there is no assignment and no function is assigned to it. How does it work?

Comment: tried to explain below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552002/2312051

**tl;dr**

> 'declare' is used to tell the compiler 'this thing (usually a variable) exists already, and therefore can be referenced by other code, also there is no need to compile this statement into any JavaScript"

When referencing [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript)

---

in [docs:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html)

> Declaration.
>
> Use declare var to declare variables. If the variable is read-only, you can use declare const. You can also use declare let if the variable is block-scoped.

```
/** The number of widgets present */
declare var foo: number;
```

`FormWithRedirect` is a declaration which describes how const will be used/returned. i.e. it will be a Functional Component with `FormWithRedirectProps`

It's a short hand for defining the interface/types that a particular variable will accept/return.

From my understanding, using declare is a shorthand for the compiler to 1. not explicitly create a definition for the instance of `FormWithRedirect` and 2. reference `FormWithRedirect` type inference at a later time (before you implement the const)

---

**Example:**

instead of coupling const with the assignment

```
const FormWithRedirect: FC<FormWithRedirectProps> = () => {
  ...whatever
}
```

some place, (declare that FormWithRedirect *will and should exist* somewhere)

```
declare const FormWithRedirect: FC<RedirectWithProps>
```

Expect implementation elsewhere

```
const FormWithRedirect = () => {}
```