# ReferenceError: VUE_APP_CONFIG is not defined Jest unit tests failing

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

```
export interface VueAppConfig {
    API_URL: string;
    API_URL_V2: string;
}

declare const VUE_APP_CONFIG: VueAppConfig;

export const APP_CONFIG = { ...VUE_APP_CONFIG } as const;
```

In above code am getting reference error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was: jest was not receiving this value am not sure why, but after updating jest.config.js to accept

```
globals: {
    VUE_APP_CONFIG: true,
},
```

it all started working fine

Answer (score 0):

[`declare` tells the compiler that the variable already exists somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript). It's not actually creating the variable.

If you're trying to create the variable, remove `declare`.

Given the name (`VUE_APP_CONFIG`), I'm guessing you're trying to read an environment variable, where the [`VUE_APP_` prefix makes the variable avaiable in the production build](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables). In that case, make sure to refer to it via `process.env`:

```js
const VUE_APP_CONFIG = JSON.parse(process.env.VUE_APP_CONFIG) as VueAppConfig
```

Comment: My code works on browser, but fails when I run jest unit