# React typescript '=' expected. TS1005

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting error with

```
'=' expected.  TS1005
  
   5 |  * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.    
   6 |  */    
>  7 | import type { NewPlugin, Optionsz, OptionsReceived } from './types';
     |             ^
   8 | export type { Colors, Config, Options, OptionsReceived, OldPlugin, NewPlugin, Plugin, Plugins, Printer, Refs, Theme, } from './types';
   9 | export declare const DEFAULT_OPTIONS: Options;    
  10 | /**
```

[image: Error]

Updated code base from index.d.ts:

```
    import type { NewPlugin, Options, OptionsReceived } from './types';
    export type { Colors, Config, Options, OptionsReceived, OldPlugin, NewPlugin, Plugin, Plugins, Printer, Refs, Theme, } from './types';
    export declare const DEFAULT_OPTIONS: Options;
    /**
     * Returns a presentation string of your `val` object
     * @param val any potential JavaScript object
     * @param options Custom settings
     */
    export declare function format(val: unknown, options?: OptionsReceived): string;
    export declare const plugins: {
        AsymmetricMatcher: NewPlugin;
        ConvertAnsi: NewPlugin;
        DOMCollection: NewPlugin;
        DOMElement: NewPlugin;
        Immutable: NewPlugin;
        ReactElement: NewPlugin;
        ReactTestComponent: NewPlugin;
    };
    export default format;
```

Updated and add tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "esnext"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react"
      },
      "include": [
        "src"
      ]
    }
```

Anyone know how to fix this error? Thank you so much

Comment: @ConnorLow what's invalid about it? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html but agreed.. share code not pictures of code =(

Comment: Just added code in my post! Sorry about this

Comment: Apologies, I misread it as an attempt to import a variable named `type` from *./types*. What does your *tsconfig* look like?

Comment: @ConnorLow just added my tsconfig

Comment: There's no reason to have `type` between `import` and `{`. Similarly, there's no need for `declare` in there either, AFAIK.

Comment: I agree with @HereticMonkey, it should be `import {...} from './types'` without the `type` word.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I believe using `import type` allows you to safely import types without increasing the size of the output JS: *"`import type` only imports declarations to be used for type annotations and declarations. It **always** gets fully erased, so there’s no remnant of it at runtime."* ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html))

Comment: can you share lines 1-4?

Comment: @ConnorLow TIL:) Thanks! I've never seen it used.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? Note that you've imported `NewPlugin, Options, OptionsReceived` twice. I'm also not sure why you'd want to `declare` a type (which would have to be created elsewhere - see [Purpose of declare keyword in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43335962/215552)), then try to use it as a default export. That type doesn't exist; it's merely there for TypeScript to be able to tell what type to give something.

Answer (score 0):

remove **type** keyword :

```
import  { NewPlugin, Options, OptionsReceived } from './types';

export  { Colors, Config, Options, OptionsReceived, OldPlugin, NewPlugin, Plugin, Plugins, Printer, Refs, Theme, } from './types';

export declare const DEFAULT_OPTIONS: Options;
```

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I solved this by upgrading `typescript` to `3.8+`

```bash
npm install typescript@^3.8
```

ref:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html
- https://blog.51cto.com/u_15072920/4818871