# type or interface inside class in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types, interface

I have a generic class that uses another derivative type (based on that generic type). I'd like to define the derivative type inside the class so I do not have to write it every time but TypeScript throws me an error.

current version (working):

```
class MyClass<T> {
    t: T

    doSomeThing(f: (t: T) => void) {}

    doAnotherThing(g: (t: T) => void) {} 
}
```

The version I want (not working):

```
class MyClass<T> {
    static type FT = (t: T) => void
    // throws error: I can't define type or interface inside class
    
    t: T

    doSomeThing(f: FT) {}

    doAnotherThing(g: FT) {} 
}
```

What is the right approach and solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please write an example of how you're gonna call it

Comment: This is not possible; there's a longstanding open feature request as [ms/TS#7061](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061). Currently the workaround is to define it outside the class as a separate generic as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0zeGw).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I prefer your solution to Dimava (both works though) but I could not accept it as the answer since you did not write it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment:  All you had to do was say "yes, that fully addresses the question, please write an answer" and I would have done it.  Since you already accepted another answer I'll just disengage.

Comment: @jcalz sorry :( I will be more careful next time. If you write the answer, I will accept it though

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in having someone else's answer unaccepted; maybe @Dimava will just edit their answer with a link to [ms/TS#7061](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061). It's more or less the same as my solution anyway; they just put it in a namespace so it looks like it's in the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a declared prop, or maybe a namspace

```
class MyClass<T> {
    // it's instance property. It does not exists actually.
    declare readonly FT: (t: T) => void;
    
    doSomeThing(f: typeof this.FT) {}
    doAnotherThing(g: MyClass.FT<T>) {} 
}
declare namespace MyClass {
    export type FT<T> = (t: T) => void
}

new MyClass<123>().doSomeThing
//                 ^?
// (method) MyClass<123>.doSomeThing(f: (t: 123) => void): void

new MyClass<123>().doAnotherThing
//                 ^?
// (method) MyClass<123>.doAnotherThing(g: (t: 123) => void): void
```

Comment: This works very well. Thank you!
Though I preferred to not write typeof. Anyhow, it works and is good enough for my use case.
I am going to ask chatgbt what instance property (and declare) is. Thanks.

Comment: @AliKhosro - [What is `declare`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552002/211627) | "instance" is the opposite of "static".

Comment: @JDB I just asked "what does declare keyword does inside class in typescript" and bard.google gave me a very good explanation. Please do so. I can't paste its answer due to SOF policy. chat.openai gives similar satisfying answer.

Comment: It'd be even better if you declared it as private so that external modules don't get confused about a non-existent property.