# Why does esbuild completely break my TypeScript enum?

Tags: typescript, esbuild

Risk.ts:

```
declare enum Risk {
  Red = 'red',
  Orange = 'orange',
  Green = 'green',
  Grey = 'grey',
}

export default Risk
```

service_worker.ts:

```
import Risk from './lib/Risk'
```

The esbuild output looks like this, and is of course completely unusable:

```
// ./lib/Risk.ts
var Risk_default = Risk;
```

Comment: Try `enum` instead of `declare enum`.

Comment: Remove the `declare`. You're defining nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of declare keyword in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript) If not, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76141803/edit) the question to clarify why it doesn't.