# Is declare just an inline replacement for ambient modules in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have read through the Typescript docs, and still do not understand when the `declare` keyword should be used.

In the [Declaration Files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) section of the docs, the keyword is only mentioned sporadically. Sometimes it is used ahead of function declarations, other times not. Sometimes in d.ts files, other times not.

The keyword is also mentioned in [Ambient Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#ambient-modules):

```
declare module "path" { ... }
```

I have also read other SO posts and articles on it, like this: [Purpose of `declare` keyword in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript)

In the SO post above, the answers state that `declare` is used to add types to values living outside our code. However, up until now I have used ambient modules for that purpose and never needed `declare` (other than in the ambient module itself).

Is the `declare` keyword just an inline replacement of ambient modules, in TypeScript? If not, are there other occasions when `declare` is needed/useful?

Comment: Maybe this could be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335962/purpose-of-declare-keyword-in-typescript

Comment: @victorSantiagoManzanilla Thanks, but I read that before posting and it just added to the confusion. Ambient modules is recommended by the TS docs, when it comes to adding types to values that exists in the runtime but has no corresponding file. I am currently thinking that `declare`'s only purpose is in the ambient module file, or to inline those types inside the module where the types are needed (instead of having them in that separate ambient module file).

Comment: This still looks like a duplicate of the other question, even if you don't like the answers over there. Could you [edit] the question so that it's clearly distinct?  Maybe make the question explicitly and clearly about when you should use ambient modules vs when you should use inline `declare`? Also there are different uses of `declare` that don't seem to be directly relevant here, like [this](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for chiming in. The other SO answer simply states that declare is used for values that do not have a declaration. However, I have been using ambient modules for that purpose, as suggested by the docs. So I do not understand when `declare` should be used instead of ambient modules (if the use cases directly overlap, which is also unclear to me). Does that make sense? To be clear, the other post could just as well have been about ambient modules, as opposed to the declare keyword. It does not clarify when the latter should be used instead of the former.

Comment: @jcalz Slight tangent to the question, but do you know how TS includes all d.ts files, regardless of name, without them being imported? For instance, *ambient module* files and *module augmentation* files are both picked up automatically, without any triple-slash reference or import. I do have their paths in the project's `tsconfig` (I specified just the single dot in `include`, to include all files), but I don't get why all d.ts files are suddenly picked up even with that root path set. Any link to the docs would be really helpful (I read through a couple of times without luck).

Comment: @jcalz I updated the question, hopefully it is more distinct now. The source of my confusion is the docs, which keep using `declare` sporadically, especially in the Declaration Files section. It would be helpful to understand whether these uses are in fact unnecessary (that we do not need `declare` in a normal d.ts file), and that `declare` is only required in the cases discussed in the OP (and the class situation you pointed out).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm equipped to write up an answer about all the ways `declare` is used and if there's some "better" or "worse" way to use it.  My basic intuition is "use `declare` to declare things without having to implement them" and I don't really know of a reason why you'd prefer one structure to another except that presumably you're trying to represent some already-existing runtime stuff.  I'm not going to wade further in here as the question is currently (I'm not saying you should change it, just that I don't feel I can answer this without being a book-length treatise full of opinion)

Comment: @jcalz Understood, thanks. Is your understanding that declare is needed when declaring functions and variables in a d.ts file? Looking at this doc page, for example, declare is used infront of some values but not others: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html (I can't find a pattern).